# Windows http.sys alternative for linux platform

Tags: linux, windows, http.sys

Windows has a Kernel based http.sys Web server. The main advantage of it is that it is kernel based. This gives performance advantages but (for me) more importantly: flexibility.

For example two applications can respond to the same port but different HTTP subkeys So /store can be handled by app1 and /status by app2. I am talking about static and dynamic content.

My question is:

Is there something similar  / an alternative on the Linux platform?

Comment: There used at least to be some sort of in-kernel HTTP server on Linux (for static content). But it probably has been abandoned, because that was not worth the effort.

Comment: @Basile: That is probably kHTTPd and was only used for static content. Dynamic content was bassed through to a single process (as I read it).

Comment: Probably yes. But I believe that Linux has faster syscalls than Windows, so in-kernel HTTP service is not worth the effort. Use a good user-land HTTP server like `lighttpd`

Comment: @Basile. That would be fine, but is it possible to use multiple applications for different subkeys; Hopefully yes so I won't need to rewrite so many things. I know Apche and you can load modules but in my case do I really need different applications given the current setup.

Comment: I was just looking for this. Maybe the question should be clarified though. While having http serving in the kernel may or may not have merit what's interesting here isn't the serving but rather the routing. Http.sys allows processes to register an url to listen for with little need for central configuration. Much like how a process might open a tcp port in most systems with out central configuration, in the age of micro services this seems like a reasonable service from the host os.